# How do I Convert a subset of fields in all documents to $toDouble?

Tags: mongodb, type-conversion, field, multiple-columns

I have a database with many documents structured like so:

```
Date:2021-01-02T08:00:00.000+00:00
FIT_ME44_Volume:"984385"
LT_MJ01:"0"
LT_MJ08:"0"
LT_MJ16:"-34.526024"
FIT_ME56_Volume:"0"
FIT_MJ22_Volume:"9538598"
LT_MJ26:"-61.803848"
FIT_ME52_Volume:"2734271"
LT_ME16:"0"
FIT_MJ28_Volume:"0"
LT_ME29:"2.10552"
LT_ME02:"2.005206"
LT_ME50:"8.732683"
FIT_MJ13_Volume:"0"
FIT_ME02_Volume:"1131376"
FIT_ME23_Volume:"2585415"
LT_ME03:"6.918576"
FIT_MJ08_Volume:"0"
FIT_MJ18_Volume:"0"
QQCr_Total_Plant:"5471052"
FIT_ME03_Volume:"103164"
FIT_ME51_Volume:"3587575"
LT_ME06:"24.423439"
FIT_ME46_Volume:"1619"
```

What I would like to do is convert all fields in all documents except `Date` from string to double. I can do this on a field by field basis, but how do I accomplish this in bulk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try an [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) query starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- `$objectToArray` convert root document from object to key-value array of object format
- `$map` to iterate loop of above converted array
- return `k` key as it is
- `$cond` to check is key in the provided array then don't convert means ignore and return existing value, you can also add fields name if don't want to convert
- else `$toDouble` to convert a string value to double
- `$arrayToObject` back to convert above key-value array of objects to an real object format
- `$replaceRoot` to replace above converted object to root

```
db.collection.updateMany(
  {},
  [{
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $map: {
            input: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" },
            in: {
              k: "$$this.k",
              v: {
                $cond: [
                  { $in: ["$$this.k", ["Date", "_id"]] },
                  "$$this.v",
                  { $toDouble: "$$this.v" }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YCVoykE5zg4)